# Google AppEngine Deploy Error (cloud-error-reporting)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-error-reporting

I have an App (PHP 7.4) running on Google AppEngine Standard. Now i have created
a new Project inside [CloudConsole](https://console.cloud.google.com) wih same settings and want to deploy
this App to the new generated Project for testreason.

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project=testapp-2022-08-14
```

But i am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/srv/vendor/google/cloud-error-reporting/src/prepend.php' (include_path='.:/layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

To activate the Cloud-Error-Reporting i followed this Documentation:
[CloudErrorrEPORTING](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/php?hl=de#enabling_the_library)

my php.ini

```
auto_prepend_file = '/srv/vendor/google/cloud-error-reporting/src/prepend.php'
session.gc_maxlifetime = 259200
opcache.memory_consumption = 128
```

my app.yaml

```
runtime: php74
instance_class: F1

entrypoint: serve bootstrap.php

handlers:
  ...
  
env_variables:
  ...
  
runtime_config:
  document_root: .

automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 20
```

any help is welcome

Answer (score 1):

Using AppEngine's standard configuration with PHP 7.4 runtime, we encountered the same issue recently, and the value set for **auto_prepend_file**
registering the library in **php.ini** in the standard setting no longer works. As we checked the sample repository, we discovered that they suggested registering error handlers manually as a workaround if php.ini cannot be accessed.

In our case, registering the error handler manually, resolved the issue.

```
# This works for files in the root of your project. Adjust __DIR__ accordingly.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/google/cloud-error-reporting/src/prepend.php';
```

Take a look at the sample repository and verify that your configuration is set up correctly as well.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/6609166f71b1049f45360480963c2327b00b7959/appengine/standard

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. This solved the Problem. And i found another solution, which worked for me. To use this in `php.ini` i use a leading dot in the path `./vendor/....`

Comment: Thanks, registering the error handler manually worked for me as well. However using a leading dot in the php.ini path didn't work.